# Cross-account access to invoke AWS lambda in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

This is how I am granting an external AWS account invoke permissions on my lambda.

```
    myLambda.grantInvoke(new iam.AccountPrincipal('account_id_b'));
```

Ran *cdk deploy*

*Resource-based policy* has the following json as seen in the console

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "generated_Sid",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account_id_b:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "my_lambda_arn"
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed steps here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-cross-account-lambda-integrations.html to create API gateway that can call this lambda from account_id_b account.

Testing API gateway from account_id_b results in following logs:

```
Fri Mar 06 03:00:07 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
Fri Mar 06 03:00:07 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 500
```

What additionally do I need to do to set this up properly?

Answer (score 0):

The policy should have the following form:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "what-ever-sid",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "my_lambda_arn",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "api_gateway_arn"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically here you give the permissions to api gateway service to call your function. The api can be in different account than your function.

For testing and simplicity you can get rid of `Condition`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked. Adding *Condition* did not though. This a bug? Tried adding like so:    ```const invokePrincipal = new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com', {
      conditions: {
        ArnLike: {
          'AWS:SourceArn': 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:account_id_b:*/*/GET/'
        }
      }```

Comment: @rake did it work for you? Do you mind sharing some code even if it's anonymized? I am trying to configure a cross account authorizer and I keep getting an error.